# Visual Studio 2010 Disable Designer Code Generation for particular ascx controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, dotnetnuke

I am currently developing a website for a Berkeley Club in Visual Studio 2010 Prof. Ed. using Asp.net and Dotnetnuke v6. This will be my second time encountering this specific problem/hassle. I created a new control (ascx file) and have been working on it some. I wanted to add the Dotnetnuke htmleditor since its sick so added the required code. Namely...

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="TextEditor" Src="~/controls/TextEditor.ascx"%>

<dnn:TextEditor ID="EmailContent" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="100%" />
```

I also had to change the ascs.designer.cs file so that instead of reading

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.UserControl EmailContent;
```

it read like

```
protected global::DotNetNuke.UI.UserControls.TextEditor EmailContent;
```

This makes it use the DNN TextEditor which is what I want. The problem is that whenever VS uses the designer to autogenerate code it overwrites the bottom line with the top line. This means every time I change the ascx file I have to change the designer again. This has gotten annoying, but I have not been able to find a way to fix it. Any ideas on how to disable the VS designer for specific controls or for segments of code in a autogenerated designer file?

Comment: why do you need to change the declaration of the EmailContent field in the designer? The designer file is there specifically for VS to generate, never touch it! (and you shouldnt have to)

Comment: @Pedro, sometimes designer code generation does not work correctly when there are compilation errors or parsing errors (with aspx/ascx file). Will advise to check errors/warnings in "Error List" and try to fix as much as possible (especially designer errors). Designer errors are not compiler errors, hence one could not run application. Further, you will see designer error only if you open relevant files - so will advise to open both page(aspx) and control (ascx) to see if designer related errors/warning exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `EmailContent` declaration in the `ascx.cs` file, and remove it from the `ascx.designer.cs` file. This will prevent the designer from messing up the type.

This goes to ascx.cs:

```
protected global::DotNetNuke.UI.UserControls.TextEditor EmailContent;
```

Comment: Tried it out and it looks like it works. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Visual Studio is interpreting the path `~/` to mean the root of *your* project, instead of the root of the DotNetNuke website (how it will resolve at runtime).

If your module project that you're working on is located in a DotNetNuke site which is hosted in your local IIS, you can setup the project to know where it's actual root is.  In the project's properties, go to the Web tab and make sure that it's setup for IIS.  The project URL should be the URL to your module (e.g. `http://mysite.dnndev.me/DesktopModules/MyModule`) and then check the "Override application root URL" checkbox and enter the website's root there (e.g. `http://mysite.dnndev.me`).  This should allow Visual Studio to realize where `~/controls/TextEditor.ascx` points, and find the right type.

That said, this works for us about 90% of the time, but we've had some projects where this doesn't work for whatever reason, and then we resort to [@mika's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199759/visual-studio-2010-disable-designer-code-generation-for-particular-ascx-controls/7200916#7200916) of moving the declaration from the designer file to the codebehind file.

Comment: Excellent answer. It's easy to try these steps first, and fall back to codebehind solution if anything goes wrong (see [DNN Blog](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryId/3074/WAP-Projects-and-DNN-TextEditor.aspx) article). Either way, I haven't been able to get full design view support, for what its worth. The design view always complains about "the file '~/controls/TextEditor.ascx' was not found".